# Recursive Regex with Joined Results

Tags: regex

My input files are html files with no extension. Desired output is regex matched URLs from all files from the root_dir and results joined in single file. My regex works and I can output results from a single file.

```
import re
with open('/Users/files/filename') as f:
    for line in f:
        urls = re.findall (r"([\w%~\+-=]*\.mp3)", line);
        print (*urls)
```

I could use glob but unsure how to:

```
import glob
import re
root_dir = '/Users/files/'
for filename in glob.iglob(root_dir + '**/*.*', recursive=True):
        urls = re.findall (r"([\w%~\+-=]*\.mp3)", line);
        print (*urls)
```

Comment: no regex recursion in pythan, yes ?

Comment: Your first code sample works on opening a directory `open('/Users/files/')`?? Your second code sample misses an `open(filename)` statement.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys no it does not open directory, i fixed the code to show that.

Comment: @Edward so you are saying there is no way to recursively use regex in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
import re, glob                                 # Import the libraries

root_dir = r'/Users/files'                      # Set root directory
save_to_file = r'/Users/urls_extracted.txt'     # File path to save results to
all_files = glob.glob("{}/*".format(root_dir))  # Get a glob with filepaths

with open(save_to_file, 'w') as fw:             # Open stream to write to
  for filename in all_files:                    # Iterate over the files
    with open(filename, 'r') as fr:             # Open file to read from  
      for url in re.findall(r"[\w%~+\-=]*\.mp3", fr.read()): # Get all matches and iterate over them
        fw.write("{}\n".format(url))            # Write each URL to write stream
```

Note that the dash must be escaped in the regular expression if you meant a `-` character and not a range.

Comment: Thank you, this worked well. Is there any way you could include some comment describing the code above or is it too cumbersome?

Comment: @x0rz0r Added comments